# PhysicalFileProvider from URL

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to get the static files (images, css, .js) from some URL:www.**** 
    
where I have stored on cloud

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() 
{
    FileProvider = new 
PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
"MyStaticFiles")), 
    RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles"), 
 });
```

Instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` I want to pass url where I have stored my files on cloud.

Comment: Then you have to write your own File Provider. PhysicalFileProvider is, as it names says for physical files. but whats your use case? If the files are stored on the cloud/cdn, then just link them in your razor templates or whatever you are using

Comment: Thanks @Tseng, but is there any  other way instead linking link on view , so that i can define relative and virtual path for css,.js,images

Comment: What is your clound? Is it public? You may try `HttpClient` to request the file in Cloud, and then return the stream from your controller.

Comment: ya , i have public path on S3 bucket.